# Textures into Unity

Tags: unity

I have seen this question over way too many forums and youtube video's etc, however none seem to work. Everyone seems to have an answer but it always seems to be followed by a "haven't tested this myself" style comment or similar.

All I am trying to do is export an FBX with embedded textures to unity. I have tried baking textures with cycles, I have tried the copy path option on the export fbx settings and I have tried clicking: file > external data > pack all into .blend.

None of these options take the textures or create a texture folder in the required designination. 
Was hoping exporting to Unity would of been slightly more intuative than this but nevermind.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

(I know this one has been done to death but not sure if something has broken in blender 2.8 update or new versions of unity?)

Comment: Thanks for the quick responce. Sort of, I think the general idea is that Blender doesn't embed the textures very well for use with unity. Think Im going to have to manually drag and drop everything. Was hoping there would of been a quicker way but don't think there is. Thanks for your help.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures/57541

Comment: So after some intece messing around I found that if the materials have their own folder i.e. colour is within a COL file, metallic is within a MET file e.t.c. and the fbx export has copy paths selected with the icon next to it checked then the textures should go with the fbx.